# Unity: 2D shadow sprite on a 3D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I'm making this game whose world is 3D, but with 2D, sprite based characters

Right now i'm having trouble with the shadows (which was working fine when everything was 2D, it was a dark ellipse with low opacity that had the same transform.position.x as the character.

[I don't want part of the shadow to stay behind the floor as happens here[image]

if i increase the shadow object's y, it becomes fully visible, but then it gets misplaced in regard to the character.

Comment: Hm...can you try to give us a better idea of what you want the shadow to look like in conjunction with the character? It's presently a little unclear what you're trying to achieve, which makes suggesting a solution difficult. If you're trying to show a shadow in 3D, it should be parallel to the ground, not perpendicular to it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the shader/material you're using, you may be able to play with the draw order to make the character sprite draw after the environment, effectively making the shadow draw after (and therefore "on top") of the floor. But this would cause issues if you have foreground elements you may want your character to walk behind.

What I would suggest, aside from using Unity's lighting/shadow system (which you may not want to use for mobile efficiency or artistic reasons), is to have the shadow as a second object that could be follow the player's x and z position, but would be "stuck" to the ground via a raycast.

Can you show a screenshot/example of the effect you wanted? Or perhaps the way it looked when you had it working in 3d?

Comment: I thought it was solved, but not really. I will post a screenshot of how it was on the 2D version

Answer (score 0):

The shadow is a full ellipse (the sprite is a full ellipse)and it appears behind the character and in front of the background image. It is currently not happening like that because the shadow object (which has a script that tells it to follow the character's x and z coordinates) intersects with the cube surface that is the world's floor
[image]